# Changing a only div's background color for every category

Tags: html, css

I have a menu based on 5 categories: main-dish,trimmings,salad,soup and salad.

Every category will have 1 or more products.

When the user will click on one product,i want to modify the background color of the div,but i want to have only one selected product on every category,so if the user will have 3 products and he clicks on the first product,the background color will change and after that,if he will click on the second product, the first div will return to the normal background color(white or something like this) and the second div's background color will have another color(blue or something like this).

To understand better, this is how i want to look at the end:

Main dish  maindish1(normal bg color/unselected) maindish2(normal bg color/unselected) maindish3 (another bg color/selected)

Trimmings trimming1(normal bg color/unselected) trimming1(another bg color/selected) trimming1(normal bg color/unselected)

Salad   salad1(normal bg color/unselected) salad2(another bg color/selected)

Soup  soup1(another bg color/selected) soup2(normal bg color/unselected)

Desert desert1(another bg color/selected)

I've tried using `:focus`,but this will change the background for only one div(or maybe i did it wrong).

The HTML:

```
<div id="menuday-container">
<h1>Meniul zilei</h1>
<div id="menuday-products-container">
    <div id="menuday-main-dish" class="menuday-item">
        <h3 class="product-subtitle">Felul Principal</h3>
        <div class="menuday-items-container">
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="1">
                Ceafa de porc
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="2">
                Carne de berbecut
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="3">
                Piept de pui
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menuday-trimming" class="menuday-item">
        <h3 class="product-subtitle">Garnitura</h3>
        <div class="menuday-items-container">
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="1">
                Cartofi prajiti
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="2">
                Cartofi nature
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menuday-salad" class="menuday-item">
        <h3 class="product-subtitle">Salata</h3>
        <div class="menuday-items-container">
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="1">
                Salata de varza
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="2">
                Salata de sfecla rosie
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menuday-soup" class="menuday-item">
        <h3 class="product-subtitle">Ciorba</h3>
        <div class="menuday-items-container">
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="1">
                Ciorba de perisoare
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product">
                Ciorba de legume
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product">
                Ciorba radauteana
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menuday-desert" class="menuday-item">
        <h3 class="product-subtitle">Desert</h3>
        <div class="menuday-items-container">
            <div class="menuday-product">
                Crema de zahar ars
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product">
                Clatite cu ciocolata
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary orange-button-with-transition">Plaseaza comanda</button>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    #menuday-container{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#menuday-container h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}
#menuday-products-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.menuday-item{
    flex: 1;
}
.menuday-item h3{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.product-subtitle{
    text-align: center;
}
.menuday-items-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.menuday-product{
    text-align: center;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.menuday-product:hover{
    background-color: #DCD0C0 ;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menuday-product:focus{
    background: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 506px){
    .menuday-items-container{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .menuday-product{
        flex-basis: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JS Code ? ­

Comment: I don't have any js code beacuse i didn't really knew how to start

Comment: Start by adding a click eventListener to the products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery in order to achieve this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".menuday-product").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
 #menuday-container{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#menuday-container h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}
#menuday-products-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.menuday-item{
    flex: 1;
}
.menuday-item h3{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.product-subtitle{
    text-align: center;
}
.menuday-items-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.menuday-product{
    text-align: center;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.menuday-product:hover{
    background-color: #DCD0C0 ;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menuday-product:focus{
    /* background: black; */
}

.menuday-product.active {
  background-color: #00ccdd;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 506px){
    .menuday-items-container{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .menuday-product{
        flex-basis: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuday-container">
<h1>Meniul zilei</h1>
<div id="menuday-products-container">
    <div id="menuday-main-dish" class="menuday-item">
        <h3 class="product-subtitle">Felul Principal</h3>
        <div class="menuday-items-container">
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="1">
                Ceafa de porc
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="2">
                Carne de berbecut
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="3">
                Piept de pui
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menuday-trimming" class="menuday-item">
        <h3 class="product-subtitle">Garnitura</h3>
        <div class="menuday-items-container">
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="1">
                Cartofi prajiti
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="2">
                Cartofi nature
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menuday-salad" class="menuday-item">
        <h3 class="product-subtitle">Salata</h3>
        <div class="menuday-items-container">
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="1">
                Salata de varza
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="2">
                Salata de sfecla rosie
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menuday-soup" class="menuday-item">
        <h3 class="product-subtitle">Ciorba</h3>
        <div class="menuday-items-container">
            <div class="menuday-product" tabindex="1">
                Ciorba de perisoare
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product">
                Ciorba de legume
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product">
                Ciorba radauteana
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menuday-desert" class="menuday-item">
        <h3 class="product-subtitle">Desert</h3>
        <div class="menuday-items-container">
            <div class="menuday-product">
                Crema de zahar ars
            </div>
            <div class="menuday-product">
                Clatite cu ciocolata
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary orange-button-with-transition">Plaseaza comanda</button>
</div>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b66jdq4s/)

Comment: if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)